# Sharing of request object between two web application

Tags: java, tomcat, cross-domain, wurfl

I have two web applications, `WebA` and`WebB`, deployed on  different tomcat. I want to send request object from`WebA` to `WebB`. I had used `wurfl` in WebB application for getting information about browser and operation system etc..or other work.
On WebA application I want to show that data graphically(just like analytics).so for this purpose i had to pass request object to WEbB application.please suggest any way to pass request object from WebA to WebB with same session.

Comment: If you are talking about stats, shouldn't you just write to a stats db from webB and read from such db from WebA?

Comment: @SJuan76 In my application user come at WebA application first.and then webA used WebB application for logging purpose or to store data..so there is no interaction of user to WebB directly.so is it possible to send request object from WebA to WebB?

Comment: There are about a million different ways to send data to a remote machine - from creating a new web service to serializing the object over a dedicated connection. How about you do a bit more research, *try* something and come back with some more specific questions?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a proxy, passing everything from webA to webB. The request object contains: request parameters, http headers, cookies. You could try to write a simple proxy yourself (with the help of HttpClient) opening a connection to webB and setting all the necessary data.